# Help in Indexers code

Tags: c#

I'm currently studying indexers chapter, but I'm unable to understand "this[int pos]" and "this[string data]" of the following code. Could anyone help me in this?

```
class OvrIndexer
{
    private string[] myData;
    private int         arrSize;

    public OvrIndexer(int size)
    {
        arrSize = size;
        myData = new string[size];

        for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
        {
            myData[i] = "empty";
        }
    }

    public string this[int pos]
    {
        get
       {
            return myData[pos];
        }
        set
       {
            myData[pos] = value;
        }
    }

    public string this[string data]
    {
        get
       {
            int count = 0;

            for (int i=0; i < arrSize; i++)
            {
                if (myData[i] == data)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count.ToString();
        }
        set
       {
            for (int i=0; i < arrSize; i++)
            {
                if (myData[i] == data)
                {
                    myData[i] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One accesses the index by integer, and the other by string:

```
var indexer = new OvrIndexer();

// Sets the first item of the indexer to "Value1"

indexer[0] = "Value1";

// Sets the item identified by key "Key2" to value "Value2"

indexer["Key2"] = "Value2";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just the defining of indexers for your class, so you can use syntax like this to get the contents of the class internal array.

```
myOvrIndexer[3]
```

will return the 4th element of the myData array.

```
myOvrIndexer["Test"]
```

will return the first element with the content *Test*.

Note that this class is mostly useless as it just wraps a array and do not add any useful functionality except the indexer receiving a string instead of index, but from a learning perspective this class should do a good job explaining whats going on.

The main purpose of the indexers is to avoid having to create methods, and thereby having to write syntax like this:

```
myOvrIndexer.GetElement(3);
myOvrIndexer.SetElement(3, myValue);
```

I think we both agree that this syntax looks better:

```
myOvrIndexer[3];
myOvrIndexer[3] = myValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

`this[int pos]`

The getter will return the value at index specified.

The setter will set the value at the index specified.

whereas

`this[string data]`

The getter will return the count of occurances of the value you are looking up.

The setter will replace all value matches found with the new value.